# FETCHING SCRAPBOOK ALBUM INTO OUR APP

Tags: facebook

we are testing some functionality of our iOS app related to facebook where we have "user_photos" permission.

Our App will fetch photos from Facebook and put that in App Gallery. A user can go ahead and create their personalized albums in App once the Facebook photos are synced in App Gallery.

Below are the account details
email: rahul.chona@appster.in

When we try to fetch the list of user's albums from his account, all the albums are listed as desired except the one "Scrapbook Album"

Piece of code we used to fetch user's facebook albums

request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"/me/albums", parameters:["fields":"images,from,tags,created_time,id","after":(self.facebookPhotoModel?.paging?.after)!,"limit":"100"])

Please advise if there is any API to fetch the user's scrapbook album

Comment: What is scrapbook album?

Comment: Thanks, WizKid, for looking into my query.
you may find detailed info about scrapbook at this address: https://www.facebook.com/help/1530275617253660/

Comment: As a conclusion, Till date, we cannot fetch scrapbook from facebook. It's a private feature of facebook which is not exposed to 3rd party apps till now.